# WPF: CheckBox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I'm dynamically filling a `DataGrid` and I'm also trying to make some columns as `CheckBox` columns. And I'm doing it this way :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("First Column", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Second Column", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Third Column", typeof(CheckBox));
    foreach (var i in Query)
        {
            List<Object> temp = new List<Object>();
                temp.Add(i.FirstValue);
                temp.Add(i.SecondValue);
                temp.Add(new CheckBox { IsChecked = false});                
            dt.Rows.Add(temp.ToArray());
        }
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Unfortunately what I see in my DataGrid is a `System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox`, I've also tried the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and also `DataGridTemplate` but only the object's reference goes there. So what is the right way to put the `CheckBox` in the `DataGrid` from the code. (I know how to do it in **XAML** but I wanna know how to do it from the code behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the third column as type `bool`. WPF should automatically render it as a checkbox.

Example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("First Column", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Second Column", typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("Third Column", typeof(bool));
foreach (var i in Query)
{
    List<Object> temp = new List<Object>();
    temp.Add(i.FirstValue);
    temp.Add(i.SecondValue);
    temp.Add(false);  // false => unchecked, true => checked.       
    dt.Rows.Add(temp.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Sorry but of what type is your `Query` object in the foreach loop?

Comment: @heiiRa I have no idea. I just copied that part from the question.