# WPF DataGrid checkbox binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox, binding, datagrid

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I'm having trouble getting a checkbox to bind to a list properly.  The rest of the properties of the list bind just fine, but the checkbox is having issues.  Here's what I have:

In the class that serves as the template for each object in the list I have:

```
Property Process As New CheckBox
```

In the MainWindow_Loaded Event I have:

```
Dim ProcessCol As new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
ProcessCol.Header = "P?"
ProcessCol.IsReadOnly = False

...

InputGrid.ItemsSource = InputData 'Which is a list of my Order Allocation objects which contains the checkbox property

...

Dim ProcessBinding As New Binding("Process")
ProcessBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
ProcessCol.Binding = ProcessBinding

...

InputGrid.Columns.Add(ProcessCol)
```

When I try to populate this collection and look at the items I get checkbox = nothing.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here... I know I couldn't be too far off...

Edit:  I changed the property to "new CheckBox" and now I get an initialzied checkbox object in the list item as "System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox Content: IsChecked:False which in this case should have been true.  So maybe a step closer, but still not there.

Comment: Any reasons for not using XAML?

Comment: I'm just not that good with the XML yet.  I'm aware it can be done using XML, but I was having trouble getting the exact effect I was looking for using XML.  At the moment I have it set up such that a user can enter data into the datagrid manually or drop a workbook on the form to populate it.  I'm also setting it up to import data from emails, but they requested a checkbox column to select items to process which is the only part I'm having problems with.  If you have an example of how to do this using XML I'm game.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:  [WPF: CheckBox in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081918/wpf-checkbox-in-datagrid?rq=1)

Technically not an answer to my original question, but it works.  Rather than a checkbox property in my class I now have a boolean property.  The column is still created as a checkbox column.  It works.

If a column can be bound to a chebox property of a list I'd still be interested in hearing that, but for me this solution works.